# All events that would trigger the applicationWillResignActive & applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone

I know pressing Command-L can trigger **applicationWillResignActive:** from forum here.

1) Is it only applied to IOS4?

2) Besides, in the real scenario with the device, what would trigger the  **applicationWillResignActive:** & **applicationDidBecomeActive:**?

I searched answers in this forum. Some said it depends the reply of a call, some said sms, some said only an app which pops up a view. Is there a list of events I can find?

Answer (score 1):

`applicationWillResignActive:` is called before the phone goes to sleep, but it’s also called any time that your application loses the ability to
respond to touch events.